# Что с комментариями в аудите?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Вчера попытался написать комментарий в очереди проверок, но получил такое сообщение:

[image: скриншот]

Что здесь не так:

1. `This is an audit` надо бы перевести.
2. Если я уже знаю, что это аудит, то есть ли смысл продолжать проверку?
3. `It was initially closed as` тоже надо бы перевести.

Comment: Мне вот при попытке комментирования написало такое: `Это всего лишь проверка, чтобы оценить вашу внимательность. Вы прошли проверку. Это сообщение уже удалено, но мы всё равно благодарим вас за отзыв его автору.` Правда, была другая очередь - первых сообщений.

Answer (score 1):

1. Предлагаю (уже сделал, но если не нравится - переделаем) следующий перевод для [`This is an audit`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/100786647?key=1b0c74d9b3d4cbfa2634c3d2acf1536b):

   > Это проверка внимательности
2. Видимо вывод хинта основывается на идее, что если уж участник начал писать комментарий, значит он не бездумно давит кнопки, а вникает в суть проверки.
3. [`It was initially closed as`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/102074529?key=5c777f078d55cf40bb4549f20de2c29a) упоминалось в чате недавно. [Уже локализовано](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=33860866#33860866) как:

   > Ранее был закрыт как **$reason$**

   Должно быть доступно при обновлении версии сайта выше, чем текущая (2016.12.1.4272)

Comment: А где версию сайта смотреть?

Comment: @Qwertiy в самом низу любой страницы. И это только п.3 касается. Т.к. для п.1 надо строки подгрузить ещё раз с помощью Nicolas'а.